# Uk visa in transit

Tags: visas, uk, transit, fees-and-charges

My husband and I applied for a Visa in transit. We applied seperately but when we had to pay online our amount for our visas was different. Is it possible to pay different amounts for the same visas?

Comment: There is very little information here. Exactly what visa did you each apply for? What amount were you charged?

Answer (score 1):

Transit visa fees vary depending on whether you applied for:

- Direct Airside Transit visa (DATV) - £35
- Visitor in Transit visa - £64

https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa

If you both applied for the same type of visa, you should have paid the same fee.